# MSMQ ignoring transaction scope

Tags: c#, msmq, transactionscope

I'm trying to read data from an MSMQ private Queue and I'm trying to Test a failure so that I can be confident that if the process doesn't finish, then the details stay on the queue. At the moment within my transaction scope it hit's my throw new Exception line and drops into the catch block as expected, but it looks as though the transaction.Complete gets run, because after the exception has been thrown, the queue is empty: here's my code snippet -

```
try
        {

            using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {

                Message incoming = new Message
                {
                    Formatter = formatter,
                    AcknowledgeType = AcknowledgeTypes.FullReceive,
                    Recoverable = true

                };

                incoming = msgQ.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3), MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);

                if (incoming != null)
                {
                    MemoryStream mem = (MemoryStream) incoming.BodyStream;
                    mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    IFormatter ifm = new BinaryFormatter();
                    var deserialisedMessage = (TravelMessageServiceObjects) ifm.Deserialize(mem); 
                    ISubmissionsService submissionsService = new SubmissionsService();
                    bool retVal = submissionsService.PerformSubmission(deserialisedMessage.Products, deserialisedMessage.PolicyReference);
                    if (!retVal)
                    {

                        string errorMessage = string.Concat("Policy Ref: ", deserialisedMessage.PolicyReference,
                            " Product: ", Enum.GetName(typeof(Products), deserialisedMessage.Products));
                        throw new Exception(errorMessage);
                    }
                }
                transaction.Complete();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            IError logger = new Logger();
            logger.Log(this, SeverityEnum.Warning, ex);

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your queue as transactional

[image]

And set `MessageQueueTransactionType` to `Automatic`. `Single` just works with internal Message Queuing transactions.

```
incoming = msgQ.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3), MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);
```

Check, [MSDTC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174499(v=sql.80).aspx) is working.

Check, firewalls don't block communication

Comment: Yes this is transactional.

Comment: I have also tried changing the transactionScope class to a MessageQueueTransaction.                              MessageQueueTransaction transaction = new MessageQueueTransaction(); try { transaction.Begin(); Message incoming  = msgq.Receive(new TimeSpan(0,0,3), transaction); and now I get an error on the Receive line of: The transaction operations sequence is invalid

Comment: I have set the transactionType to Automatic and now I receive the following error : Cannot import the transaction.

Comment: @bilpor it's better, check MSDTC is working on all servers included in process

Comment: Ok, on the Server that hosts MSMQ I have the MSDTC set to use the local coordinator the server name is called 'MessagingServer'. On the machine that is trying to read from the queue I have set the remote coordinators host name to 'MessgingServer'. Now when I try to run I receive the following error: Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed

Comment: @bilpor check firewalls. they may block communication